# Web-service returns "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable"

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I created web service and hosted it on the IIS 7. At first it was perfectly working, but when the service runs too long (about one day or more) it becomes unreachable and returns:

> "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

Comment: have you check that server is overloaded?

Comment: Check EventViewer of server, any error related to IIS, or .NET Runtime

Comment: Yes I checked it. Is there any tool to check the specific service ram/processor usage?